# Computing the high bits of a multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, multiplication

I'm trying to convert an open source library from .Net 4.0 to 3.5 and cannot easily convert the following long multiplication code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the most significant 64 bits of the 128-bit
        product x * y, where x and y are 64-bit integers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the most significant 64 bits of the product x * y.</returns>
    public static long mul64hi(long x, long y)
    {
 #if !NET35
        BigInteger product = BigInteger.Multiply(x, y);
        product = product >> 64;
        long l = (long)product;
        return l;
 #else
        throw new NotSupportedException(); //TODO!
 #endif
    }
```

As you can see the author didn't find a way to do this. `BigInteger` does not exist in .NET 3.5.

How can I compute the high bits 64 bits of a 64*64 multiplication on .NET 3.5?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link, using the J# Library I might get this to work! I'm trying it out now...

Comment: hm no not working for me, [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7xsxf8e2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says it's only avaiable in VS 5 or less, and I need to use VS2010 for the other problems (default parameters)

Comment: Since you are asking for a well known problem (high bits of multiplication) there are existing solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868367/getting-the-high-part-of-64-bit-integer-multiplication I did not find a C# solution but the C code should work as is.

Comment: @usr Thank you, I'll take a look into that one, currently following a solution wich uses the System.Numeric namespace from the Mono source code [Answer](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html) It looks very promising:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a 2N-bit multiplier from multiple N-bit multipliers.

```
public static ulong mul64hi(ulong x, ulong y)
{
    ulong accum = ((ulong)(uint)x) * ((ulong)(uint)y);
    accum >>= 32;
    ulong term1 = (x >> 32) * ((ulong)(uint)y);
    ulong term2 = (y >> 32) * ((ulong)(uint)x);
    accum += (uint)term1;
    accum += (uint)term2;
    accum >>= 32;
    accum += (term1 >> 32) + (term2 >> 32);
    accum += (x >> 32) * (y >> 32);
    return accum;
}
```

It's just elementary-school long multiplication, really.

With signed numbers, it's a bit harder, because if intermediate results carry into the sign bit everything goes wrong.  A `long` can't hold the result of a 32-bit by 32-bit multiply without that happening, so we have to do it in smaller chunks:

```
public static long mul64hi(long x, long y)
{
    const long thirtybitmask = 0x3FFFFFFF;
    const long fourbitmask = 0x0F;
    long accum = (x & thirtybitmask) * (y & thirtybitmask);
    accum >>= 30;
    accum += ((x >> 30) & thirtybitmask) * (y & thirtybitmask);
    accum += ((y >> 30) & thirtybitmask) * (x & thirtybitmask);
    accum >>= 30;
    accum += ((x >> 30) & thirtybitmask) * ((y >> 30) & thirtybitmask);
    accum += (x >> 60) * (y & fourbitmask);
    accum += (y >> 60) * (x & fourbitmask);
    accum >>= 4;
    accum += (x >> 60) * (y >> 4);
    accum += (y >> 60) * (x >> 4);
    return accum;
}
```

Inspired by harold's comment about Hacker's Delight, the signed version can be made just as efficient as the other, by carefully controlling whether intermediate results are or are not signed:

```
public static long mul64hi(long x, long y)
{
    ulong u = ((ulong)(uint)x) * ((ulong)(uint)y);
    long s = u >> 32;
    s += (x >> 32) * ((long)(uint)y);
    s += (y >> 32) * ((long)(uint)x);
    s >>= 32;
    s += (x >> 32) * (y >> 32);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Oh, to be honest I didn't expect this to work;) And I can't really control the solution, its somewhat of 4trillion (9 trillion is the max value?) Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Seneral: Make sure to run a bunch of unit tests.  Because you have signed numbers, some of the intermediate results can carry into the sign bits, I'm not sure if that will corrupt the final result.

Comment: @Seneral: I think I have a version that should work on negative numbers also.  Added it.

Comment: Could the signed version be improved by using the " High-Order Product Signed from/to Unsigned"-thing from Hacker's Delight or wouldn't that be any better?

Comment: @harold: That section doesn't help, but the note above it about using a mixture of signed and unsigned for the intermediate results would.

Comment: `mul64hi` fails when multiplying very large numbers - for example, `UInt64.MaxValue * UInt64.MaxValue`. `System.Numerics.BigInteger` says the result should be `18446744073709551614`, but this calculates `18446744069414584318`

Comment: @Cocowalla: Thanks for noticing that, now fixed at least the unsigned version.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank was fast, and it seems to work perfectly now!