# Getting the high half and low half of a full integer multiply

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, multiplication, unsigned-integer

I start with three values A,B,C (unsigned 32bit integer). And i have to obtain two values D,E (unsigned 32 bit integer also). Where

```
D = high(A*C);
E = low(A*C) + high(B*C);
```

I expect that multiply of two 32bit uint produce 64bit result. "high" and "low" is just my covnention for mark the first 32 bits and the last 32 bits in 64bit result of multiply.

*I try to obtain optimized code of some allready functional one. I have a short part of the code in huge loop which is just few command lines, however it consumes almost all of computational time (physical simulation for couple of hours computing). That's the reason why i try to optimized this little part and rest of the code could remain more "user-well-arranged".*

There is some SSE instructions that are fit for compute mentioned routine. The gcc compiler probably do optimized work. However i do not reject an option to write some piece of code in SSE intructions directly, if it will be necessary.

Be patient with my low experience with SSE please. I will try to write an algorithm for SSE just symbolically. There will be probably some mistakes with ordering masks or understanding the structure.

1. Store four 32-bit integers into one 128-bit register in order: A,B,C,C.
2. Apply instruction (probably pmuludq) into mentioned 128-bit register which multiply pairs of 32-bit integeres and return pairs of 64-bit integers as result. So it shoudld calculate multiply of `A*C` and multiply of `B*C` simultaneously and return two 64-bit values.
3. I expect that i have new 128bit register values P,Q,R,S (four 32-bit blocs) where P,Q is 64-bit result of `A*C` and R,S is 64-bit result of `B*C`. Then i continue with rearrange values at register into order P,Q,0,R
4. Take first 64 bits P,Q and add second 64 bits 0,R. The result is a new 64 bits value.
5. Read first 32 bits of the result as D and last 32 bits of the result as E.

This algorithm should return correct values for E and D.

**My question:**

Is there a static code in c++ which generate similar SSE routine as mentioned 1-5 SSE algorithm? I preffer solutions with higher performance. If the algorithm is problematic for standart c++ commands, is there a way how to write an algorithm in SSE?

I use TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit compiler.

(note: Question was modified after advice)

(note2: I have an inspiration in this http://sci.tuomastonteri.fi/programming/sse for using SSE for obtain better performance)

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking.  Do you want to know if an operation could overflow?

Comment: Note that `4294967296` is `1ull << 32`.

Comment: Using `uint64_t` seems simpler and more efficient than alternatives (as doing multiplication "manually" with `uint16_t`).

Comment: NathanOliver: Not "if" but "how many times". I just wonder if there is a clever command in c++ for A*B/C operation without losing precision and using types with double memory size. One of the example is dividing by 2^32 (where dividing could be interpreted as count of overflows).

Comment: @MarekBasovník Integer overflows aren't indicated at runtime. How overflows are implemented is compiler specific. Thus there's no way to _count them_ either.

Comment: Like I said in comments on Grabusz's answer, x86 has a 32b*32b -> 64b multiply (which already produces the high and low half of the result in separate registers, all set for doing `low32(A*C) + high32(C*B)`.  So if you just need both halves of the result of a 32b multiply, use that.  It might be worth vectorizing anyway, though, depending on what the surrounding code is like.  If you give us some hint about that, maybe we can help you vectorize.  Your pre-edit version of this was definitely an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This question should really be edited to something like "Getting the high half of a full integer multiply", or something.  I think the original question (multiply, divide by a big power of two, and then "count the overflows") is nonsense, and should just go away.  But I think that's too big an edit for someone else to make, so you should do that.  The question might take a lot fewer words to state, now that you've seen what the answer might be and can ask it better. :P

Comment: You are right. I'll try.

Comment: There are indeed SSE instructions that give the high half or full product, but they're not as easy to use (nor even necessarily faster) than using a double-width built-in type. It is of course both simpler and faster than manually mucking with narrow partial products and the emulated add-with-carry

Answer (score 4):

You don't need vectors for this unless you have multiple inputs to process in parallel.  clang and gcc already do a good job of optimizing the "normal" way to write your code: cast to twice the size, multiply, then shift to get the high half.  Compilers recognize this pattern.

They notice that the operands started out as 32bit, so the upper halves are all zero after casting to 64b.  Thus, they can use x86's `mul` insn to do a 32b*32b->64b multiply, instead of doing a full extended-precision 64b multiply.  In 64bit mode, they do the same thing with a `__uint128_t` version of your code.

[Both of these functions compile to fairly good code (one `mul` or `imul` per multiply).](http://goo.gl/4CnBl7).  `gcc -m32` doesn't support 128b types, but I won't get into that because 1. you only asked about full multiplies of 32bit values, and 2. you should always use 64bit code when you want something to run fast.  If you are doing full-multiplies where the result doesn't fit in a register, clang will avoid a lot of extra mov instructions, [because gcc is silly about this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51837).  This little test function made a good test-case for that gcc bug report.

That godbolt link includes a function that calls this in a loop, storing the result in an array.  It auto-vectorizes with a bunch of shuffling, but still looks like a speedup if you have multiple inputs to process in parallel.  A different output format might take less shuffling after the multiply, like maybe storing separate arrays for `D` and `E`.

I'm including the 128b version to show that compilers can handle this even when it's not trivial (e.g. just do a 64bit `imul` instruction to do a 64*64->64b multiply on the 32bit inputs, after zeroing any upper bits that might be sitting in the input registers on function entry.)

When targeting Haswell CPUs and newer, gcc and clang can use the `mulx` BMI2 instruction.  (I used `-mno-bmi2 -mno-avx2` in the godbolt link to keep the asm simpler.  If you do *have* a Haswell CPU, just use `-O3 -march=haswell`.)   `mulx dest1, dest2, src1` does `dest1:dest2 = rdx * src1` while `mul src1` does `rdx:rax = rax * src1`.  So `mulx` has two read-only inputs (one implicit: `edx`/`rdx`), and two write-only outputs.  This lets compilers do full-multiplies with fewer `mov` instructions to get data into and out of the implicit registers for `mul`.  This is only a small speedup, esp. since 64bit `mulx` has 4 cycle latency instead of 3, on Haswell.  ([Strangely, 64bit `mul` and `mulx` are slightly cheaper than 32bit `mul` and `mulx`](http://agner.org/optimize/).)

```
// compiles to good code: you can and should do this sort of thing:
#include <stdint.h>

struct DE { uint32_t D,E; };

struct DE f_structret(uint32_t A, uint32_t B, uint32_t C) {
  uint64_t AC = A * (uint64_t)C;
  uint64_t BC = B * (uint64_t)C;
  uint32_t D = AC >> 32;         // high half
  uint32_t E = AC + (BC >> 32);  // We could cast to uint32_t before adding, but don't need to
  struct DE retval = { D, E };
  return retval;
}



#ifdef __SIZEOF_INT128__  // IDK the "correct" way to detect __int128_t support
struct DE64 { uint64_t D,E; };

struct DE64 f64_structret(uint64_t A, uint64_t B, uint64_t C) {
  __uint128_t AC = A * (__uint128_t)C;
  __uint128_t BC = B * (__uint128_t)C;
  uint64_t D = AC >> 64;         // high half
  uint64_t E = AC + (BC >> 64);
  struct DE64 retval = { D, E };
  return retval;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Related: [Getting the high part of 64 bit integer multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958815) discusses similar MSVC intrinsics, and use of GNU C `unsigned __int128`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to compute number of potential overflows in A*B. If yes then you have 2 good options - the "use twice as big variable" (write 128bit math function for uint64 - it's not that hard (or wait for me to post it tomorrow)), and the "use floating point type":
(float(A)*float(B))/float(C)
as the loss of precision is minimal (assuming float is 4 bytes, double 8 bytes, and long double 16 bytes long) , and both float and uint32 require 4 bytes of memory (use double for uint64_t as it should be 8 bytes long):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint32_t a(-1), b(-1);
    uint64_t result1;
    float result2;
    result1 = uint64_t(a)*uint64_t(b)/4294967296ull;    // >>32 would be faster and less memory consuming
    result2 = float(a)*float(b)/4294967296.0f;
    cout.precision(20);
    cout<<result1<<'\n'<<result2;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
4294967294
4294967296
```

But if you want really precise and correct answer I'd suggest using twice as big type for computing

Now that I think of it - you could use long double for uint64 and double for uint32 instead of writing function for uint64, but I don't think it's guaranteed that long double will be 128bit, and you'll have to check it. I'd go for more universal option.

---

EDIT:

```
You can write function to calculate that without using anything more
than A, B and result variable which would be of the same type as A.
Just add rightmost bit of (where Z equals B*(A>>pass_number&1)) Z<<0,
Z<<1, Z<<2 (...) Z<<X in first pass, Z<<-1, Z<<0, Z<<1 (...) Z<<(X-1)
for second (there should be X passes), while right shifting the result
by 1 (the just computed bit becomes irrelevant to us after it's
computed as it won't participate in calculation anymore, and it would
be erased anyway after dividing by 2^X (doing >>X)
```

(had to place in the "code" as I'm new here and couldn't find another way to prevent formatting script from eating half of it)

It's just a quick idea. You'll have to check it's correctness (sorry, but I'm really tired right now - but the result shouldn't overflow at any point of calculation, as the maximum carry would have value of 2X if I'm correct, and the algorithm itself seems to be good).

I will write code for that tomorrow if you'll still be in need of help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that more information about the problem is probably needed. So i edited my question.

Comment: @MarekBasovnik by "left part of of C*B multiplication" you mean something like C*B mod 2^32? (the reminder of dividing C*B by 2^32), or how many times C*B did overflow the unsigned int? I'm pretty confused by the new explanation. I also don't know what you mean by "throw away the overflow part"... some compilers nullify your int and mark it as unusable if you overflow them.

And I wouldn't add only few lines of assembly as it can slow down the program (compiler can't optimize the code the way it wants).

Comment: I am a numerical mathematican, not skilled programmer. That's why of my formulation is little vague, i am sorry. We know that multiply of 2 integer numbers with some range N has result as integer with range 2×N in general. If i look into SSE2 instruction set, there is an operation to multiply two 32bit integers with full untruncated 64bit result saved in register (that's why i expect simple solution in c++ code). I just need to take a result of multiplication of two intgers and both of part (first 32 bits and second 32 bits) i need to use for different purpose (store them in different values).

Comment: @MarekBasovník: x86's `mul` instruction does a 32b*32b->64b full multiply, storing the result in `edx:eax`.  The 64bit version does 64b*64b->128b (`rdx:rax`).  x86's divide instruction divides `rdx:rax` by the source, storing quotient in `rax` and remainder in `rdx`.  (So it's a 128b/64b->64b operation, or 64b/32b->32b).  Look for a wrapper for these operations that you can use in c++, rather than trying to actually detect overflow and do something about it. You might also find https://gmplib.org/ useful.

Comment: @Marek: If you're doing something that could benefit from doing several multiplies in parallel, then sure have a look at SSE (esp. SSE4.1 brought a lot of good stuff for 32/64bit integers).  See the [x86 tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links, including to Intel's intrinsics guide for use of this stuff from C++.  (But you'd also need a tutorial to learn the basics).  Note that SSE/AVX has *no* integer division operation.  It does have vector FP division, including double-precision, but of course `double` can only represent a limited range of 64b integers exactly.

Comment: Grabusz: local variable don't consume memory unless you use a lot of them.  They each take up a register.

Comment: @MarekBasovnik if you only need it for 32 bit variable, and can use 64 bit var for calculating this then I would suggest doing this:
uint32_t(uint64_t(x)*uint64_t(y)>>32) - for 32 most significant bits (overflowed part)
uint32_t(uint64_t(x)*uint64_t(y)) - for the 32 least significant bits

If you can't use 64 bit variables then use asm or do some binary math

Comment: @PeterCordes: aren't there only 4 registers avaliable for the programmer?

Comment: @Grabusz: 32bit x86 has 7 general-purpose regs (not counting the stack pointer).  64bit x86 has 15 (not counting the stack pointer).  Of course they get used up quickly holding pointers and temporaries, not just named variables.  My point was that a 64bit variable doesn't use any extra memory or registers, assuming you don't run out of regs.  It still uses up one register.  (This is assuming you compile for 64bit, which you should because 32bit has been obsolete for years.  Esp. for Marek's own personal use, `-O3 -march=native` is appropriate, to take advantage of everything his CPU has.)

Comment: BTW, re: formatting, you can use backticks ( ` ) to put small bits of things in code-style formatting inside a sentence.  I guess your paragraph of "code" was to avoid triggering italics from `*`?