# Getting the high part of signed integer multiplication in C++

Tags: c++

How can I manually calculate the high part for a **signed** multiplication in C++? Like [Getting the high part of 64 bit integer multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868367/getting-the-high-part-of-64-bit-integer-multiplication) (unsigned only), but how do I calculate carry/borrow?

I do not mean that cast in a larger type (thats simple), but really manual calculation, so it works also with int128_t.
My goal is to write a template function that always returns the correct high-part for signed and unsigned arguments (u/int8..128_t):

```
template <typename Type>
constexpr Type mulh(const Type& op1, const Type& op2) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<Type>)   return ???;
    else                                    return see link;
}
```

Comment: You have to use unsigned arithmetic or compiler intrinsic functions and/or non-standard modes like -fwrapv because signed arithmetic overflow is undefined behavior in C++ and avoiding it is quite inefficient.

Comment: I've implemented adc/sbb (uint8..128_t) and addh/subh (u/int8..128_t) in my library; these functions could be used.

Comment: You can piece-wise multiply the 64-bit numbers into 4 smaller 32-bit multiplies and related adds and shifts.  Slow, but portable and extendable to any size.

Comment: This is a legit question.  Why VTC as unclear?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are implementing things that are usually available as
compiler [builtin functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).

Implementing those in standard C++ results with less efficient code. That can be still fun as mental exercise but then why you ask us to spoil it as whole?

Comment: I need a compiler-independent function and not builtins/intrinsics. Unfortunately, such things are not in the C/C++-standard, that's my problem.

Comment: Typical solution to that is to hide side-by-side platform-dependent solutions (using conditional compiling with preprocessor) behind common platform-independent interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do signed, then you could convert unsigned to signed `x=(x<0)?x*-1:x` get the result and then calculate the sign afterwards `z=((x<0)!=(y<0))?z*-1:z`

This works becuase the magnitude of a signed integer of arbitraty length is always going to fit into an unsigned integer of the same length, and you know that if both numbers are negative or positive the answer will be positive, if only one of them is negative it will be negative.

Comment: Sadly, that is not correct. I have a unit test for unsigned integer which runs correctly for all values (uses mulh_unsigned). When I calculate

`template <typename Type>
constexpr Type mulh_signed (const Type& op1, const Type& op2) noexcept
{
 using unsigned_type = std::make_unsigned_t <Type>;

 const bool
  neg1{op1<0},
  neg2{op2<0};
 const unsigned_type
  arg1 = neg1 ? op1 * Type{-1} : op1,
  arg2 = neg2 ? op2 * Type{-1} : op2,
  res = mulh_unsigned(arg1, arg2);

 return (neg1 == neg2)? res : res * Type{-1};
}`

crash it at op1 = -128 and op2 = 1 with Type=int8_t :-(

Comment: @Gero - but how do you fit -128 into an 8 bit signed value? The negative value with largest magnitude an 8 bit signed integer can hold is -127!

Comment: The range of int8_t is -128 ... 127. The issue is likely in something else there. @Gero should debug what the actual issue is.

Comment: @Oo Tib - Doh!  I should have finished my coffee first!  Thanks for catching my mistake :o)