# Check int multiplication overflow in GLSL

Tags: glsl, webgl2, glsles

I know that in C or C++, you can see how much a multiplication overflowed by using a `long`
E.g

```c
int[] multiply(int a, int b){
  long long r = a * b;
  int result = r;
  int overflow = r >> 32;
  return {result, overflow};
}
```

However, in GLSL, there are no 64 bit integers. Is there a way to achieve the same result in GLSL without `long`s?

Context: GLSL 3.0, running in my browser via WebGL 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to break up the multiplication into pieces yourself.

Here is an algorithm that tries to do this for 64-bit multiplication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587262/736162

The same principles apply to 32-bit. You would need to change the code in a few ways:

- Halve the sizes of things: instead of 64-bit types, use 32-bit types; halve the shift constants; instead of casting from 64-bit to 32-bit (`(uint32_t)`), convert from 32-bit to 16-bit using `& 0xffff`.
- Make it valid GLSL 3.0 (e.g. use `out` instead of `&`, and `uint` instead of `uint32_t`)

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

By the way, you'll want to be sure you have `highp` precision on everything. `precision highp int;` at the top of your shader is enough.

Comment: How does out and in work with function parameters? Does it pass a reference instead of copying? Can it be used with arrays?

Comment: `in` is the default behaviour you're used to. `out` means that instead of passing a value into the function, it passes a value out, so it's like an extra return value. `inout` is like `out` but it first copies the value passed in, it's kinda similar in concept to a reference in C++. It can be used with arrays, though I'm not sure what the performance is like.